# How do I split a Vec<u8> based on a specific character?

Tags: sockets, rust

I'm working on developing a custom protocol in Rust, and during communication, I use '..' to separate data in the payload. For example, (using double quotes for convenience, but all are essentially of type `Vec<u8>`):

```
sysinfo:      " sysinfo",
command_input:  "command_input",
command_output: " command_output"
```

Data is transmitted in the format

```
'sysinfo..command_input..command_output'.
```

I want to split the data based on '..' and place each part into a struct like this:

```
pub struct Payload {
    pub sysinfo:        Vec<u8>,
    pub command_input:  Vec<u8>,
    pub command_output: Vec<u8>,
}
```

How can I efficiently split the data, which is of type Vec, based on '..'?

If you know of a more efficient way to communicate payload data than the method I described, I would like to learn about it.

What I've come across so far are methods involving converting to a string and using the split function before converting back to `Vec<u8>`, it this doesn't provide the outcome I'm looking for. Converting to a String seemed inefficient, and I got the sense
that it wasn't the optimal solution.

+The data is always transmitted in validated UTF-8 format. Additionally, if possible, I would like to split it into Vec format.

Comment: Conversion to `String` is essentially free if you can be sure the transmitted data is valid utf-8. If you can be 100% sure, it _is_ free with `from_utf8_unchecked`. Apart from that, why not iterate the data and check for periods?

Comment: Do you want to split it into `Vec`s or into slices?

Comment: Also, is your data always UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the [`bstr`](https://docs.rs/bstr/latest/bstr/trait.ByteSlice.html#method.split_str) crate:

```
use bstr::{B, ByteSlice};

let msg: &[u8] = b"sysinfo..command_input..command_output";

let fields: Vec<&[u8]> = msg.split_str("..").collect();
assert_eq!(x, vec![B("sysinfo"), B("command_input"), B("command_output")]);
```

Answer (score 1):

&str is the same underlying type as &[u8], so [std::str::from_utf8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) is devoid of any dynamic allocation.

You can write:

```rust
let input = Vec::from(b"sysinfo..command_input..command_output");
let from_utf8 = std::str::from_utf8(&input).unwrap();
let mut split = from_utf8.splitn(3, "..");

assert_eq!(split.next(), Some("sysinfo"));
assert_eq!(split.next(), Some("command_input"));
assert_eq!(split.next(), Some("command_output"));
assert_eq!(split.next(), None);
```

And you can convert back to Vec with:

```rust
let my_vec: Vec<u8> = "my_str".as_bytes().into();
```

If really high performance is a concern, use [std::str::from_utf8_unchecked](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html) or do yourself a for loop to split up your variables.